# Nested Loops in Perl - Failing logic

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I'm trying to work out a bigger problem, but have simplified the issue for readability, ultimately the logic below is the reason the extended program is failing.

I am using Perl to search for a short sequence of letters within a larger sequence (protein sequences), and if it is *not*  found, then I'd like to do some calculations. I don't know whether I'm going crazy, but I can't work out why this logic is failing.

```perl
sub calculateEpitopeMutations {

    my @mutationArray;
    my @epitopeArray;
    my $count;
    my $localEpitope;

    open( EPITOPESIN2, $ARGV[5] ) or die "Unable to open file $ARGV[5]\n";
    while ( my $line = <EPITOPESIN2> ) {
        chomp $line;
        push @epitopeArray, $line;
    }

    while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each our %sequencesForCalculation ) {

        foreach ( @epitopeArray ) {

            $localEpitope = $_;

            if ( $value =~ /($localEpitope)/g ) {
                print "$key\n$localEpitope\nexactly the same\n\n";
                next;
            }
            else {

                #This is where I'd like to do the further calculations

                print "$key\n$localEpitope\nthere is a difference\n\n";
                next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$ARGV[5]` is the name of a text file containing a list of 9-character sequences, exactly like the following

```
RVSENIQRF
SFQVDCFLW
```

The idea is to put these into array `@epitopeArray` and iterate through these, and compare them with all (currently just one) `$value` sequences in the hash `%sequencesForCalculation`.

`%sequencesForCalculation` is a hash, where `$value` is a long sequence of characters, like this

```
MDSNTMSSFQVDCFLWHIRKRFADNGLGDAPFLDRLRRDQKSLKGRGNTLGLDIETATLVGKQIVEWILKEESSETLRMTIASVPTSRYLSDMTLEEMSRDWFMLMPRQKKIGPLCVRLDQAVMEKNIVLKANFSVIFNRLETLILLRAFTEEEAIVGEISPLPSLPGHTYEDVKNAVGVLIGGLEWNGNTVRVSENIQRFAWRNCDENGRPSLPPEQK
```

Currently, the small 9-character long sequence `$localEpitope` *is* contained in the longer sequence `$value` so when I iterate through the program, I should get this printed every time.

(`$key` contains a header of information about the protein sequences, but is irrelevant so I have shortened it to just the variable name.)

```
$key
RVSENIQRF
Exactly the same
$key
SFQVDCFLW
Exactly the same
$key
```

But instead I'm getting this

```
$key
RVSENIQRF
exactly the same
$key
SFQVDCFLW
there is a difference
$key
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if anything further is required.

Comment: If the small sequence is contained in the long sequence, then shouldn't you get the "...exactly the same" output?

Comment: Exactly, but i'm not. I can't figure out why

Comment: `each our %sequencesForCalculation` ... Why is there an `our` in there? Where does `%sequencesForCalculation` come from?

Comment: But that is the opposite of what you said in your post.

Comment: It comes from a previous sub, I've gone through a different text file and grabbed the sequences and put them into the %sequencesforcalculation hash. The keys are from that different  file also.

Comment: Please note what [mob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) and I have said. Your question says that you should get the `there is a difference` message every time, but you also say *"`$localEpitope` is contained in the longer sequence `$value`"*. Those two are contradictory, and we can't tell what it is that you mean

Comment: Mob, sorry I can't see what you mean? The output I'm getting should be "exactly the same.." Both times, as he smaller sequence is contained in the larger sequence. But I'm getting one of each output Ie, one saying "exactly the same" and one saying "there is a difference".

Comment: Okay, but your question says *"I should get this printed every time ... `there is a difference`"*

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the output I should be getting is "exactly the same" - apologies

Comment: Okay please fix your question

Comment: I've just updated it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

***TL;DR***: You should change `$value =~ /($localEpitope)/g` to `$value =~ /$localEpitope/`

Okay now that we know the real circumstances, the problem (as [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) points out in his comment) is that you have the `/g` modifier on your pattern match. There's no reason for that; you don't want check *how many* times the substring appears, you just want to know whether it's there at all

The problem is that variables subjected to a `/g` pattern search keep a state that says where the last search ended. So you're searching for `$epitopeArray[0]` in the longer string and finding it, and then searching for `$epitopeArray[1]` *from where the previous search terminated*. The first substring appears *after* the second one, so only the first is found

For more information on this behaviour, take a look at the [`pos` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html) which returns the current value of this state. For instance `pos($value)` will return the character offset where the next `m//g` will start its search

This short program demonstrates the problem. With the `/g` modifier only `BBB` is found. Remove it and both are found

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $long_s = 'xxxAAAxxxBBBxxx';

for my $substr ( qw/ BBB AAA / ) {
  if ( $long_s =~ /$substr/g ) {
    say "$substr okay";
  }
  else {
    say "$substr nope";
  }
}
```

#### output

```
BBB okay
AAA nope
```

---

#### Original

You say

> Currently, the small 9-character long sequence (`$localEpitope`) IS contained in the longer sequence (`$value`), and so when I iterate through the program, I should get the following printed everytime

So `$localEpitope` is a substring of `$value` and you're saying that

```
$value =~ /($localEpitope)/g
```

evaluates to ***true***

That is correct behaviour. `$value =~ /$localEpitope/` will check whether `$localEpitope` can be found anywhere in `$value`

Unfortunately it's not clear enough from what you've written to suggest a solution

Comment: The `/g` flag is highly suspicious, though.

Comment: @melpomene: You're right. Well done. I've been too busy clarifying the question. Do you want to write it up?

Comment: thanks very much everyone. It's appreciated, apologies for the mistake with the question

Comment: @user1146453: That's fine. I think you should take a look at [*Markdown Editing Help*](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so that you can format your posts better